# Is there a way to play a youtube video on a React Native App and display just the video not youtube?

Tags: react-native, youtube

I am using a WebView to play youtube videos but I want to play just the video not show that it is from YouTube. I found another component but it plays only video links ending in mp4. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Embed and normal urls of Youtube videos are different.

**Normal:** https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DGQwd1_dpuc

**Embed:**  https://www.youtube.com/embed/DGQwd1_dpuc

So, you should change 'watch?v=' with '/embed/'.

Also, adding parameters such as 'showinfo=0' or 'controls=0' can help.

Example:

```
<WebView
    style={{ flex: 1 }}
    source={{
               uri: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/DGQwd1_dpuc?rel=0&autoplay=0&showinfo=0&controls=0",
           }}
    javaScriptEnabled={true}
 />
```

But you should know that Youtube logo, title and some ui elements will still be visible.